# # of days in a month based and start and end dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This question relates to [Calculate Total Number Of Days Per Specific Month](https://superuser.com/questions/979752/calculate-total-number-of-days-per-specific-month).

If you look at the original question what IF you have a start and end date Jan - March and you need to know how many days are within each month between that range?

So A2 and B2 I have the start and end dates and from C1 - Q1 I have Jan to Dec. so on Cells C2 - Q2 I need to have a formula letting me know number of business days per month based on the start and end dates.

Can you help?

Comment: Post a few samples of time frames and also post the expected outcome. Explain the logic that you have applied to arrive at the result. Make sure to include time frames that have holidays for the country that this applies to. Update your question with these details and then post a comment to alert people who follow this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the kind of result you want:

[image: Screenshot]

You pick a start and end date to produce a list of how many days for each month are within that range. The important thing here is that the values in `C1:N1`  are actual date values that have been formatted. This is *much* easier than using text values and then trying to calculate dates in your formula.

The formula in `C1` is

```
=IF(OR(MONTH($A2)>MONTH(C$1),MONTH($B2)<MONTH(C$1)),0,MIN($B2,DATE(YEAR(C$1),MONTH(C$1)+1,0))-MAX($A2,C$1)+1)
```

which you then drag over and down. There are a few oddities, though:

1. If the date range in `A:B` goes beyond your column headings, all results are zero.
2. If there is no entry, Excel sees that as a zero value - which is a valid date - and that screws it up.

However, this should be enough to get you started. You can tweak it to fit your exact needs.